# How to add osgi service reference in JAVA

Tags: java, spring, apache-camel, activemq-classic, jbossfuse

I'm new to `fuse` and developing a component test.

I need to call the component that implements `ActiveMQ` (outside `fuse`) in Java.
In `Spring` it would be something like this:

```
<osgi:reference id="activemq" interface="org.apache.camel.Component"
    filter="(component.name=ActiveMQ)"/>
```

But I don't know how to reference this component in Java.

---

Finally I found the way:

```
BundleContext ctx = FrameworkUtil.getBundle(YourClass.class).getBundleContext();

ServiceReference[] sRef;

sRef = ctx.getServiceReferences(Component.class.getName(), "(component.name={{YourComponentName}})");

Component amqComponent = (Component) ctx.getService(sRef[0]);

context.addComponent("activemq", amqComponent);
```

Comment: Thanks you rkm_Hodor_king :)

Comment: @Marta Cruz, when you resolve your own question, you must not include the answer in the question. Instead you have to add it as a separte answer

Answer (score 0):

From outside, you need to use any of the transport connectors the ActiveMQ broker provides, usually its JMS over port 61616, but it can be configured on the broker side. Then its just standard JMS / spring-jms / camel-jms to use  the ActiveMQ JMS client and configure that to use JMS (= called openwire protocol) on port 61616.

As this is non OSGi realted then there is a lot of information on the internet how to do that. Or check out some of the Camel examples etc.

- https://github.com/apache/camel/tree/master/examples